# Vlookup doesn't work with column of string

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have 4 columns, containing 2 columns of names and 2 columns of values, as below. I need to update Column B with value in K, if the name1 = name2. Both name columns are formatted as text, and values columns are formatted as numeric.

```
(A) Name1     (B) Value1       (J) Name2     (K) Value2
     A                               A             123    
     B                               B             456   
     C                               X             000   
     D                               Y             000   
     E                               Z             000  
     F                               C             789
```

I insterted the following vlookup in the first row of column B, but it returns the name in column A.

```
=VLOOKUP(A4,J2:J22890,K2:K22890)


I'm expecting to have the following result:
    (A) Name1     (B) Value1       (J) Name2     (K) Value2
         A              123              A             123    
         B              456              X             000   
         C              789              B             456   
         D                               Y             000   
         E                               Z             000  
         F                               C             789
```

Am I using vlookup a the wrong way? or is it due to the fact that I'm looking up strings??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I can't edit the post because it's not enough characters and I can't comment because I don't have enough rep...
`=VLOOKUP(A4,$J$2:$K$22890,2,0)`

This is Alex's post with absolute references for the lookup table array.

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be

```
=VLOOKUP(A4,J2:K22890,2,0)
```

`1.`First parameter is the value you are looking for,

`2.`second one is the range (it can be multiple columns, with the referenced data in the most-left column of the selection),

`3.`followed by the column's number where the records should be retrieved from,

`4.`and lastly a flag (1 or 0) if you would like to accept similar results (1) or exact matches only (0)